# Standard format for rendering epub file in android

Tags: android, epub, html-rendering

I am developing application based on epub. After googling, i can able to unzip the file and take the content of the book and render into the html page. Below link is reference link where i took the code

[siegmann](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android)

[Chaek](http://code.google.com/p/chaek/)

Now the problem is each epub file contains different path for taking the content of file. so code in above link may not support some epub file for rendering. My application need to render all the epub file. Is there any standard format for rendering the epub file like "aldiko" has done.

If any standard format please guide me. Its very urgent. Its already running out of time.

Comment: What do you mean by different paths? Within the .epub package itself (e.g. the chapter files are in different locations), or different .epub files on the device?

If it's the former, the main .opf file lists out the path of every file in the package; you can parse that XML and grab the contents that way.